# how to pass data from one uitableview to multiple controllers by clicking on different cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have one View controller that have UITableView and after that i have two different view controller first name is WebLabelViewController and second is LabelViewController. i did some coding but still something wrong. i want to assign different view controllers on each cell means when i click on first row cell it will take me webLabelViewController when i click 2 row cell it should take me LabelViewController and every things work fine but the problem is in segue.. when i am clicking on first cell my viewController send data to webViewController perfectly means index[0] but when i m clicking on second cell its sending data but data from first cell means same index[0] and its should be index[1].. so i m confused...
here is some code that i wrote... and please help me i m new in coding.

**interface file means viewController.h**

```
import < UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
}

@property NSArray *firstArray;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

***implementation file with code ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "WebLabelViewController.h"
#import "LabelViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = _firstArray[0][@"cellname"];
    _firstArray = @[ 
        @{@"cellname":@"Stud", @"detail":@"STUDYc", @"about":@"M ",      @"link":@"http://"},
        @{@"cellname":@"Onlin", @"detail":@"UK", @"about":@"MM ", @"link":@"http:/"},
        @{@"cellname":@"Becom", @"detail":@"J ", @"about":@"QM ", @"link":@"http://www.},
        @{@"cellname":@"Contact Us", @"detail":@"TELEP", @"about":@"q ", @"link":@"http"},
        @{@" cellname ":@"About Th", @"detail":@"GIFT", @"about":@"M", @"link":@"http"},
    ];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_firstArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = _firstArray[indexPath.row][@"cellname"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = _firstArray[indexPath.row][@"detail"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue 1" sender:self];
    } else if (indexPath.row >= 1 && indexPath.row <= 3) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue 2" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue 1"]){
        //  NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        WebLabelViewController *wlvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        wlvc.xyz = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _firstArray [path.row][@"about"]];

        wlvc.abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _firstArray [path.row][@"link"] ];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue 2"]) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        LabelViewController *lbvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        lbvc.def = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _firstArray[path.row][@"about"]];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the selected row index in an integer variable? Save it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the `NSIndexPath` as `sender` when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`.  `sender` can be any object you like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue 1" sender:indexPath];
    } else if (indexPath.row >= 1 && indexPath.row <= 3) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue 2" sender:indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue 1"]){
       NSIndexPath *path = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
        WebLabelViewController *wlvc = (WebLabelViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        wlvc.xyz = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.firstArray[path.row][@"about"]];
        wlvc.abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.firstArray[path.row][@"link"]];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue 2"]) {
        NSIndexPath *path = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
        LabelViewController *lbvc = (LabelViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        lbvc.def = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.firstArray[path.row][@"about"]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My train of thought for this; subclass a TableViewCell and add a viewController property to it.

Here a good reference if you want to learn how to subclass a cell.

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

You could build out a method in the custom cell that will instantiate the viewController. Assuming that you would attach a button to this cell; clicking the button on the cell can launch the viewController.

The specifics on how to display the viewController depends on whether or not you are using storyboards/nibs or programmatically creating it.